# Populate a Select Drop Down in Meteor with JSON from a url?

Tags: javascript, json, meteor

How would you create a page of RECENT LOTTERY RESULTS using Meteor and the following JSON located at:
[LOTTERY DATA](http://data.ny.gov/resource/d6yy-54nr.json)

The following code results in a successfull call to the data as evidenced in the console but I'm not savvy enough to figure out how to display this data onto a page in Meteor.

```
Meteor.http.call("GET", "http://data.ny.gov/resource/d6yy-54nr.json", function (err, result){
my_json = result.content;
 console.log(my_json);
});
```

The console is logging the following:

```
[ {
  "draw_date" : "2015-01-17T00:00:00",
  "winning_numbers" : "15 16 23 27 36 09",
  "multiplier" : "2"
}
, {
  "draw_date" : "2015-01-14T00:00:00",
  "winning_numbers" : "02 04 10 41 53 22",
  "multiplier" : "5"
}
, {
  "draw_date" : "2015-01-10T00:00:00",
  "winning_numbers" : "02 09 19 28 29 19",
  "multiplier" : "5"
}
```

Initially just displaying any results to the page would be awesome. But ideally, I would like to be able to have a select drop down with all of the available `draw_date(s)` and when a user makes their selection, the winning_numbers would be displayed.

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: The draw dates can be easily parsed into JavaScripts date object.

Answer (score 2):

This code will do that:
I've used the result from your JSON as hard coded object since *Meteor* couldn't be loaded as an external library.

```js
var showData = [ {
  "draw_date" : "2015-01-17T00:00:00",
  "winning_numbers" : "15 16 23 27 36 09",
  "multiplier" : "2"
}
, {
  "draw_date" : "2015-01-14T00:00:00",
  "winning_numbers" : "02 04 10 41 53 22",
  "multiplier" : "5"
}
, {
  "draw_date" : "2015-01-10T00:00:00",
  "winning_numbers" : "02 09 19 28 29 19",
  "multiplier" : "5"
}];

//set a default option to the select.
var html = "<option value='' disabled default>Select a date</option>";

//iterate over each lottery drawing and add it to the select.
//The date will be displayed, the index of the array element will be the value.
showData.forEach(function(element, index){
   var date = new Date(element.draw_date);
   html += "<option value='"+index+"'>"+ date.getDate() + "/" + (parseInt(date.getMonth())+1) + "/" + date.getFullYear()+ "</option>";
   
});

//insert the option into the select.
document.getElementById("selectDate").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
//add an onchange event handler to the select.
document.getElementById("selectDate").addEventListener("change", displayWinningNumbers, false);

function displayWinningNumbers(e)
{
  //when a option is selected, test the value. If 0 or higher return the array entry with the winning numbers.
  if(e.target.value >= 0)
  {
     alert(showData[e.target.value].winning_numbers); 
  }
}
```

```html
<select  id="selectDate">
  
</select>
```

Comment: So to use the data I am receiving from the url, I would just use the my_json variable instead of the hard coded showData variable?

Comment: The method is pure javascript. Meteor doesn't have a native drop down menu. The hardcoded data is the data returned by your `http.call`. Changing it to `showData = my_json` should do it. My code should replace your console.log line :-)

Comment: How do I render the data each time I visit the template. I am using Iron:Router.  If I load the page directly, the data appears.  But if I navigate to other templates using my navigation menu and then return to the results page, the data no longer appears in the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the server-side method in `Template.rendered` and create some html elements dynamically

```
 Template.resultsView.rendered=function(){
     Meteor.call('getData',function(err,result){
      if(err){
       //Error handling code
      }else{
       var myDynamicHtml = '<option value='' default>Select a date</option>';
       result.forEach(function(el,index){
          //create you dom elements with the parsed data on results
          // append to any container with specific id
           myDynamicHtml+= "<option value='"+ele.someProperty+"' </option>";
       });
      $('#idOfContainer').html(myDynamicHtml);
       //idOfContainer is the id of html elment in template resultView where you 
       //want show the parsed data in any(<select>) html element
      }
     }); 
 }
```

Comment: Not seeing what you have here. Where are you declaring getData? where are you parsing the JSON data?

Comment: getData is the `Meteor.method` in which you are getting the json data using the `http.get`, From where you are calling `http.get` server-side method or client-side ? I thought you are calling it from a server-side method called `getData`. You said you are getting the `json` data.

Comment: The only code I have so far is the one with the my_json = result.content